# Show message after script runs with row count

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have the following PowerShell script that works fine. However, when it is run it flashes up and away very quickly.

How could I display a message if the `$rowsAffected` is greater/equal to 1 and a different message if `$rowsAffected` is 0 and have it stay on screen until enter is pressed or the window is closed?

```bsh
#Create SQL Connection
$con = New-Object "System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection"

#Set Connection String
$con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=.\SQL2017;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;user id=test;password=test;")
$con.Open()

#run query
$sqlcmd = New-Object "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand"
$sqlcmd.Connection = $con
$sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 30
$sqlcmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Execution SET Execution = 1"
$rowsAffected = $sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$con.Close()
```

Comment: add an `if` block to decide which msg to display, and then add a `pause` command to wait until a key is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to do the trick.

```
If ($rowsAffected -ge 1) 
{
    "Your request for the file has been successfully submitted and will be processed in the next few minutes. "
    pause
}
else
{
    "ERROR! No file was found. Please contact support"
    pause
}
```